# CSS Animation Not Animating When Removing Class

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have an image where I want it to go to the bottom right when I scroll past it and animate as it goes there.  This part works.

As I scroll back up, I want it to animate the same way back to it's original spot. This is where I need help.

It just jumps back to it's original spot without the transition. How can I get this to work correctly?

```js
var $window   = $( window );
var $container   = $( '.container' );
var containerTop  = $container.offset().top;

$window.scroll( function() {
 if( $window.scrollTop() > containerTop ) {
  pullContainer();
 } else {
  revertContainer();
 }
});

function pullContainer ( ) {
 $( '.container' ).addClass( 'move' );
 console.log( 'pullContainer' );
}

function revertContainer ( ) {
 $( '.container' ).removeClass( 'move' );
 console.log( 'revertContainer' );
}
```

```css
#header, #content, #footer {
 height: 75vh;
}

#header {
 background: #ccc;
}

#content {
 background: #666;
}

#footer {
 background: #999;
}

.container {
 position: static;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 transition: all 1s ease;
}

.move{
 position: fixed;
 left: calc( 100vw - 400px );
 top: calc( 100vh - 400px );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header"></div>
 <div id="content">
  <div class="container">
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/400" />
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="footer"></div>
```

Comment: I'd guess because you're switching from `fixed` to `static` so it just snaps back to 0 0. You'd have to transition the position values first...then switch the position property...I guess.

Comment: **1-** remove the `position` atributte from the .move class **2-** then change the .container position from `static` to `relative`

Comment: I agree with @Paulie_D . Look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/84s4twer/

Comment: @freestock.tk the issue with removing fixed from .move is that the container is no longer 'sticky'.

Comment: @Mojtaba the difference from the jsfiddle is that the starting state of the image is not inline with the content (middle of page in my example) it starts in the top left of the page since it is always 'fixed'.

Answer (score 1):

When you remove 'move' class, position goes directly from fixed to static so transition will not effect.
You might need another class which has position static you add it when going on top and remove it when scrolling down (something like that). Also .container which has the transition should have a position other than static in your case it should be fixed